Adding a new item to easyadmin collection field overrides the last one
I have a project using symfony 7 and easyadmin 4.
All features worked fine untill I upgraded to the latest Symfony 7 release where editing CollectionFields by adding new elements started behaving erratically.
When I add a new item in a collectionField in edit mode, it does override the last element instead of adding a new instance in the collection.
Only way to get around the issue is to revert back to version 6.4.7 of Symfony.

If you think this is a bug in EasyAdmin, please report it in their issue tracker. Maybe you're facing the problem reported in https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/6369?
